# POST Request to .net Core 7 Web API Returning Empty String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, httprequest

So I am using the following C# code running on localhost to send a POST request to a .net Core 7 web api deployed on IIS 10.

I can make successful GET requests using the C# code, however the POST requests are returning a 200 with an empty response body. I tested the POST endpoint with PostMan, as well as an AJAX request from the app, and it was successful. Both the AJAX call and PostMan request actually trigger the changes that the API method perform, but the C# code does not trigger any changes.

Also noting that when I run the API locally and point the local app to the local API, the POST works. Been banging my head against the wall for 2 weeks trying to figure this out, so any help is appreciated!

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "{URL}");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer {API_TOKEN}");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
var content = new StringContent("{\r\n  \"State\": \"PA\",\r\n  \"Zip\": \"19087\",\r\n  \"Country\": \"United States\"\r\n}", null, "application/json");
request.Content = content;
var response = Task.Run(async () => await client.SendAsync(request)).Result;
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
var ret = Task.Run(async () => await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;
```

Here is the API controller endpoint I'm trying to hit:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Venue), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Venue Venue)
{
    if (Venue == null)
        return BadRequest();

   Venue venue = _venueListDAL.UpsertVenue(Venue);
    return venue == null ? NotFound(null) : Ok(venue);
}
```

I've also tried to serialize my request data this way, where `Venue` is an object parameter in the method:

```
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Venue);
request.Content = new StringContent(data, null, "application/json");
```

Comment: Can you debug the server-side code? See if it's even entering the route and code path you're expecting it to enter? Most likely there's something subtly different about the request when it's made from your C# client, like a header or an encoding or something, and that's causing something in your server-side code to treat it differently.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I was able to step through the API code when it is run local. I even tried adding basic return messages to test when I published it to the server. I checked the CORS policy and set up preflight processing, it seems like if I try to POST to the API when it's on the server it just doesn't accept the request.

Comment: Hows your API Endpoint code looks like? Does your request hit to the endpoint? Please share more details for your API code snippet in order to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I appreciate your assistance and have updated the question with your requested information

Comment: Are you collecting any telemetry server-side (using something like Application Insights)? I'm guessing the request is getting intercepted somehow, and I would attempt to see at what layer that's happening (WAF, Load Balancer, middleware, filter, etc.)

Comment: @StriplingWarrior The biggest confusion I have with this whole scenario is that I can successfully perform an AJAX POST, but when I attempt to POST from the server-side it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

> When I run the API locally and point the local app to the local API,
> the POST works. Been banging my head against the wall for 2 weeks
> trying to figure this out, so any help is appreciated!

Well based on your description and shared code I have tried to investigate your code snippet and founded couple of inconsistencies.

First of all, it would be nicer if you could share your controller code as well. However, your first issue on your request `content` which is not in correct format.

I would recommend you to check your request model and try to serialize them accordingly.

I have tried in following way and its working as expected.

Here is the example how I tried:

Demo Controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class WebAPIRequestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("WebAPIReturningEmptyString")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> WebAPIReturningEmptyString([FromBody]  string testdata)
    {
        return Ok("Request has been received!");

    }
}
```

Clinet Request:

```
public async Task<string> CallAPI()
{

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var _requestUrl = "http://localhost:5094/api/WebAPIRequest/WebAPIReturningEmptyString";
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _requestUrl);
    //request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer {API_TOKEN}");
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    ///var content = new StringContent("{\r\n  \"State\": \"PA\",\r\n  \"Zip\": \"19087\",\r\n  \"Country\": \"United States\"\r\n}", null, "application/json");
    var content = new StringContent("\"This is a test data\"", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    request.Content = content;
    var response = Task.Run(async () => await client.SendAsync(request)).Result;
    ///var response = await client.SendAsync(request).Result
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
   // var ret = Task.Run(async () => await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;

    var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseBody;
}
```

**Note:** As you can see, I have commented few of your code which causing the unreachable API request. Because as said earlier reuqest content is not in correct format.

Another issue is you have used `Task.Run(async () => await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result;` which always be null and you cannot able to read API response.

Instead, you can do as following, in order to read API response accordingy:

```
 var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) for best practice to use [async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) call.

Comment: Thanks for breaking this down. I updated the question to include some other attempts I've made. The only issue I'm having with this answer is that I am not using an async method. The app wasn't developed for async, and I'm not ready to tackle the zombie effect that making this method would cause.

Comment: Well, that is of course another reason why its not hitting the endpoint, you are saying someone wait for me but you haven't left any place to wait, how someone can wait? When you are sying `Task.Run(async () => await client`  endpoint should have asyncrhonous mechanism, other then it would skip execution.

Comment: `Task.Run(async () => await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).Result` will not "always be null": it will block until the content is available, and then will produce the same result as `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`. It's not an _ideal_ way to get the result, but it wouldn't be the cause of the issues OP is reporting.